# Fixing navbar when scrolling beyond a certain number of pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jquery code, which fixes a navbar header on top of page when a user scrolls down to a certain pixels. But I am not sure whether is this the correct way to do this.

Because this is going to be a majorly used function by all users, it would be better if I can improve it in terms of optimizations and speed.

What basically I am doing is removing few classes and adding few classes when that breakpoint reaches.

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if(scroll > 130){
            $('#catNavBar').removeClass("navbar-static-top");
            $('#catNavBar').addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            $('.gbText').addClass('hidden');
            $('.small-logo').removeClass('hidden');
            $('#headerGbCont').css('width', '50px');
        } else{
            $('#catNavBar').addClass("navbar-static-top");
            $('#catNavBar').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
            $('.gbText').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.small-logo').addClass('hidden');
            $('#headerGbCont').css('width', '109px');
        }
    });
});
```

Can you suggest any improvements in this code? Or anything that I am doing wrong that should be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache your jQuery objects as @Abbas mentioned. Also, you could use `toggleClass` with a state switch:

```
var $catNavBar = $('#catNavBar'),
    $headerGbCont = $('#headerGbCont'),
    followScroll = $(window).scrollTop() > 130;

$catNavBar.toggleClass('navbar-static-top', !followScroll);
$catNavBar.toggleClass('navbar-fixed-top', followScroll);
// etc..
$headerGbCont.width(followScroll ? 50 : 109);
```

Regarding magic numbers like `130`, I would suggest that you calculate distances between elements and define rules based on the result rather than approximating when you should switch classes.

Answer (score 1):

You should cache your selector in a variable:

```
var $catNavBar = $('#catNavBar');

if(scroll > 130) {
    $catNavBar.removeClass("...");
    $catNavBar.addClass("...");
}
```

**Reason:** placing selectors in variables is recommended, since overusing selectors can result in poor performance.

Everytime you would call a function on `$("#colors_added")`, the whole DOM has to be parsed by the browser. This is not the case when you store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on jQuery too much.  The best place to do your styling is in your CSS file.

You can think of the scroll position is a property of the body. You only need to add or remove one class on the `<body>` element based on the scroll position.  CSS selectors apply the rules as appropriate.

```js
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 130) {
            $(document.body).addClass('scrolled-down');
        } else {
            $(document.body).removeClass('scrolled-down');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#catNavBar {
    width: 98px;
    height: 2998px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 0;
}
body.scrolled-down #catNavBar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

body.scrolled-down .gbText {
    display: none;
}

.small-logo {
    vertical-align: top;

    display: none;
}
body.scrolled-down .small-logo {
    display: inline;
}

#headerGbCont {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;

    width: 109px;
}
body.scrolled-down #headerGbCont {
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="height: 3000px; margin: 0 0 0 100px; padding: 0;">
  <header style="border: 1px solid blue; margin: 0 0 0 -100px; padding: 0; height: 129px;">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/se-logo.png">
  </header>
  <nav id="catNavBar">
    Navbar
  </nav>
  <div id="headerGbCont">
    <p>
      Small logo appears when you scroll down:
      <img class="small-logo" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/se/se-icon.png" width="50" height="50">
    </p>
    <p class="gbText">
      This <code>.gbText</code> disappears when you scroll down.
    </p>
  </div>
  <p>
    And the container changes width.
  </p>
  <p style="position: relative; top: 2980px;">Bottom of the page for this demo</p>
</body>
```

(I've inlined a lot of styles in the HTML to declutter the CSS for this illustration.  You obviously shouldn't do that in your website.)

For another demonstration of how powerful this "single master switch" technique can be, see [*iPhone notes application replica using HTML/CSS*](/a/77162/9357).